# Local notification won't send after incrementing time by one day

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponents, unusernotificationcenter

I'm creating an app that delivers daily local notifications at a time specified by the user via the app interface.

During testing, I schedule 20 daily local notifications to cover 20 days. On the last day, it's up to the user to tap the button to schedule 20 more.

When I run the app, it only sends the first notification. The remaining notifications never get sent. How can I fix my code so that the time is incremented by one day?

```
// Function that schedules the 20 notifications in advance so each one is delivered every day
func scheduleNotif() {
// Notification #1
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content.body = sendMessage()
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

// Time in which notification will fire
    let dailyTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime, repeats: false)

// The identifier for the notification so that it is distinguishable from others in code
    let identifier = "Positive Message"

    // Requesting for notification to be delivered
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
// Notification #2
    let content1 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content1.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content1.body = sendMessage()
    content1.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime1 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime1.hour! += 24
    let trigger1 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime1, repeats: false)

    let identifier1 = "Positive Message1"

    let request1 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier1, content: content1, trigger: trigger1)
    center.add(request1) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
// Notification #3
    let content2 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content2.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content2.body = sendMessage()
    content2.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime2.hour! += 48
    let trigger2 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime2, repeats: false)

    let identifier2 = "Positive Message2"

    let request2 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier2, content: content2, trigger: trigger2)
    center.add(request2) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
// Notification #4
    let content3 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content3.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content3.body = sendMessage()
    content3.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime3 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime3.hour! += 72
    let trigger3 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime3, repeats: false)

    let identifier3 = "Positive Message3"

    let request3 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier3, content: content3, trigger: trigger3)
    center.add(request3) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #5
    let content4 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content4.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content4.body = sendMessage()
    content4.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime4 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime4.hour! += 96
    let trigger4 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime4, repeats: false)

    let identifier4 = "Positive Message4"

    let request4 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier4, content: content4, trigger: trigger4)
    center.add(request4) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #6
    let content5 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content5.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content5.body = sendMessage()
    content5.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime5 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime5.hour! += 120
    let trigger5 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime5, repeats: false)

    let identifier5 = "Positive Message5"

    let request5 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier5, content: content5, trigger: trigger5)
    center.add(request5) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #7
    let content6 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content6.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content6.body = sendMessage()
    content6.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime6 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime6.hour! += 144
    let trigger6 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime6, repeats: false)

    let identifier6 = "Positive Message6"

    let request6 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier6, content: content6, trigger: trigger6)
    center.add(request6) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #8
    let content7 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content7.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content7.body = sendMessage()
    content7.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime7 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime7.hour! += 168
    let trigger7 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime7, repeats: false)

    let identifier7 = "Positive Message7"

    let request7 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier7, content: content7, trigger: trigger7)
    center.add(request7) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #9
    let content8 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content8.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content8.body = sendMessage()
    content8.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime8 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime8.hour! += 192
    let trigger8 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime8, repeats: false)

    let identifier8 = "Positive Message8"

    let request8 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier8, content: content8, trigger: trigger8)
    center.add(request8) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #10
    let content9 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content9.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content9.body = sendMessage()
    content9.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime9 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime9.hour! += 216
    let trigger9 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime9, repeats: false)

    let identifier9 = "Positive Message9"

    let request9 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier9, content: content9, trigger: trigger9)
    center.add(request9) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #11
    let content10 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content10.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content10.body = sendMessage()
    content10.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime10 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime10.hour! += 240
    let trigger10 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime10, repeats: false)

    let identifier10 = "Positive Message10"

    let request10 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier10, content: content10, trigger: trigger10)
    center.add(request10) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #12
    let content11 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content11.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content11.body = sendMessage()
    content11.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime11 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime11.hour! += 264
    let trigger11 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime11, repeats: false)

    let identifier11 = "Positive Message11"

    let request11 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier11, content: content11, trigger: trigger11)
    center.add(request11) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #13
    let content12 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content12.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content12.body = sendMessage()
    content12.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime12 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime12.hour! += 288
    let trigger12 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime12, repeats: false)

    let identifier12 = "Positive Message12"

    let request12 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier12, content: content12, trigger: trigger12)
    center.add(request12) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #14
    let content13 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content13.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content13.body = sendMessage()
    content13.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime13 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime13.hour! += 312
    let trigger13 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime13, repeats: false)

    let identifier13 = "Positive Message13"

    let request13 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier13, content: content13, trigger: trigger13)
    center.add(request13) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #15
    let content14 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content14.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content14.body = sendMessage()
    content14.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime14 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime14.hour! += 336
    let trigger14 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime14, repeats: false)

    let identifier14 = "Positive Message14"

    let request14 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier14, content: content14, trigger: trigger14)
    center.add(request14) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #16
    let content15 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content15.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content15.body = sendMessage()
    content15.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime15 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime15.hour! += 360
    let trigger15 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime15, repeats: false)

    let identifier15 = "Positive Message15"

    let request15 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier15, content: content15, trigger: trigger15)
    center.add(request15) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #17
    let content16 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content16.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content16.body = sendMessage()
    content16.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime16 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime16.hour! += 384
    let trigger16 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime16, repeats: false)

    let identifier16 = "Positive Message16"

    let request16 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier16, content: content16, trigger: trigger16)
    center.add(request16) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #18
    let content17 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content17.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content17.body = sendMessage()
    content17.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime17 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime17.hour! += 408
    let trigger17 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime17, repeats: false)

    let identifier17 = "Positive Message17"

    let request17 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier17, content: content17, trigger: trigger17)
    center.add(request17) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #19
    let content18 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content18.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content18.body = sendMessage()
    content18.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime18 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime18.hour! += 432
    let trigger18 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime18, repeats: false)

    let identifier18 = "Positive Message18"

    let request18 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier18, content: content18, trigger: trigger18)
    center.add(request18) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
    // Notification #20
    let content19 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content19.title = "Good Morning \(name)!"
    content19.body = "Please open our app and update your time to keep recieving notifications!"
    content19.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dailyTime19 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: timePick.date)
    dailyTime19.hour! += 456
    let trigger19 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dailyTime18, repeats: false)

    let identifier19 = "Positive Message19"

    let request19 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier19, content: content19, trigger: trigger19)
    center.add(request19) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)

        }

    }

}

// Connecting the button to the code
@IBAction func timeSet(_ sender: AnyObject) {
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

// Setting users name
    name = nameText.text!

// Configuring time
    timePick.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    timePick.locale = NSLocale.current

// Scheduling notification
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    scheduleNotif()


}
```

}

Comment: Whta you have done dear!!! why so code? why not a for loop for 20times?

Comment: Made the wording more succinct, clearer and less redundant.

Comment: Are you testing by manually changing the time on your device?

Answer (score 0):

You set your notification fine. But please rethink your code.

like in some function try to use like this. I am not writing your code just an example to help you to understand

```
  func someFunction() {
        for i in 1..<21 {
        var notificationR = UILocalNotification()
        notificationR = setUpNotification(notificationR)
        notificationR.fireDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(i))
        notificationR = publishLocalNotification(notificationR)
    }
}


func setUpNotification(_ notification: UILocalNotification) -> UILocalNotification {
    notification.alertBody = "Positive message"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
    return notification
}


func publishLocalNotification(_ notification: UILocalNotification) -> UILocalNotification {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    return notification
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but do you have a solution to the question i originally asked ?

Comment: notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day   just this line will repeat your notification for every day

Comment: but wouldn't that repeat the same notification everyday. I want my notifications to fire then the next notification to send 24 hours later then so on. I don't want the same notification to send everyday

Comment: then make an array of your notification messages and  in this for loop pick the messages according to index. then your interval problem and dynamic message problem will be solved.